# How to pass variable from the view to the $scope with $window service?

Tags: angularjs, scope

I want to init data in ng-init want retrieve this data in a controller.

I have a view with a form. In this form, i have the following input:

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" id="name" name="name"
                    ng-model="type.name" required="true"
                    placeholder="Enter type name..." ng-init="reftypedefinition.name='{{type.name}}'"/>
```

In Chrome Developer Tools, i see the value of reftypedefiniton name which is set :

[image]
And in my controller in with i inject $window service:

$scope.createType = function () {
    $scope.reftypedefinition.name = $window.reftypedefinition.name;

};

When i run i have the error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
    at Scope.RefTypeDetailsController.$scope.createType (http://localhost:8080/...js:74:63)
    at Parser.functionCall (http://localhost:8080/.../js/lib/angular.js:10846:21)
    at ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.element.on.callback (http://localhost:8080/.../js/lib/angular.js:19133:17)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/ism-server/js/lib/angular.js:12701:28)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/ism-server/js/lib/angular.js:12799:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://localhost:8080/.../js/lib/angular.js:19138:23)
    at HTMLButtonElement.x.event.dispatch (http://localhost:8080/.../js/lib/jquery.min.js:5:10006)
    at HTMLButtonElement.x.event.add.y.handle (http://localhost:8080/**/js/lib/jquery.min.js:5:6796)
```

What is wrong ? Why the name is not avalaible on the controller ?
Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You are not actually storing it in `$window` by using `ng-init`. You are initializing it in the scope directly. So change your code to:

```
$scope.reftypedefinition = {};
$scope.createType = function () {
    console.log('name', $scope.reftypedefinition);
};
```

Comment: You're right. I change my code but now i dont understand what happened. I the view, i have the html code ng-init="reftypedefinition.name='Test'" but in the console log i have : {name:"{{type.name}}"} the variable is evaluated in view but not in controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need create $scope.reftypedefinition object before in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ng-init="reftypedefinition={name : type.name}"
```

Comment: You're right. I change my code but now i dont understand what happened. I the view, i have the html code ng-init="reftypedefinition.name='Test'" but in the console log i have : {name:"{{type.name}}"} the variable is evaluated in view but not in controller

Comment: Angular doesn't evaluate any console log statements. Its not possible. It only evaluates the view.